# How to get last foreign key object in table B of each object in table A?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

now i have the database look like this.
[image]

And now i try to query the last `Battery_Log` object of each `Battery` object and group_by `Sites.id`, for now i can query `Battery` object and group_by `Sites.id` with this code.

```
result = db.session.query(Sites.id, func.array_agg(Battery.id)).filter(Battery.site_id==Sites.id).group_by(Sites.id).all()

# result = [(1, [1,2,3]), (2, [4, 5])]
The result is show the [ (Sites.id, [Battery.id, ... ]), ... ]
```

And my problem is i don't know how to get the latest `Battery_Log` object of each `Battery` id, the relation between `Battery` to `Battery_Log` is one-to-many so that mean each `Battery` object will have `Battery_Log` object more than one but i want only last object.

So are there any way to do that, and this is the result that i want.

```
# result = [(1, [1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1]), (2, [4, 5], [1, 0, 0])]
The result is show the [ (Sites.id, [Battery.id, ..], [Battery_Log.id, ..]), ... ]
```